# How to configure Squid to support HTTPS?

Tags: curl, https, squid

I have setup a Squid server to deploy my web crawler.

For HTTP URLs, Squid works very well, for instance:

```
curl -is -L http://www.baidu.com  --proxy http://<squid_address>:3129
```

return the source of the index page of Baidu.

However, when I try to connect to HTTPS URL, something weird happen. The following curl command returns nothing but some useless HTML code:

```
curl -is -L https://www.baidu.com  --proxy http://<squid_address>:3129
```

The result (including the response headers):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: bfe/1.0.8.14
Date: Fri, 04 Mar 2016 01:24:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 227
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Thu, 09 Oct 2014 10:47:57 GMT
Set-Cookie: BD_NOT_HTTPS=1; path=/; Max-Age=300
Set-Cookie: BIDUPSID=4617F4EBA3F7D1A94B06FFE0B72E02B7; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; max-age=2147483647; path=/; domain=.baidu.com
Set-Cookie: PSTM=1457054666; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; max-age=2147483647; path=/; domain=.baidu.com
Set-Cookie: BDSVRTM=0; path=/
P3P: CP=" OTI DSP COR IVA OUR IND COM "
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache
BDPAGETYPE: 1
BDQID: 0xd7f5c039000f7c84
BDUSERID: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Set-Cookie: __bsi=16735848709246631383_00_175_N_N_1_0303_C02F_N_N_Y_0; expires=Fri, 04-Mar-16 01:24:31 GMT; domain=www.baidu.com; path=/

<html>
<head>
        <script>
                location.replace(location.href.replace("https://","http://"));
        </script>
</head>
<body>
        <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.baidu.com/"></noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

I know the cause might be that the Baidu server detected the incoming connection is not using HTTPS (see the `BD_NOT_HTTPS=1` cookie)

How to configure the Squid server so it can support HTTPS URLs to solve this?